# Turning off lead assignment rules in triggers not working?

Tags: apex, trigger, apexrest, dml, lead-assignment

I've a rest resource in apex which upserts leads based on the lead phone number but the problem is when lead owner is changed manually from UI and again it is updated from apex rest resource the assignment rules are firing, but i don't want to fire the rules and i want to fire the rules only when created.

For that i wrote a before trigger to turn off the rules for updates but it is not working

```
trigger TurnoffAssignment on Lead (before update) {
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        System.debug('came here>>');
        for(Lead l:trigger.new){
            system.debug(l.getOptions());
            Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
            l.setOptions(dmo);
            //l.getOptions().AssignmentRuleHeader=null;
            System.debug(l.getOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

the lead assignment rules are firing though they are turned off.

how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the behavior from inside the trigger. The DML options are set from the calling context and will apply for the entire transaction. You'll have to fix the problem upstream.

Comment: Thnx @sfdcfox how do i set in apex code to run assignment rules only when record is created as i'm using the upsert operation explicitly

Comment: @bnthsrikanth You'll want to query to see if the record exists first.

Comment: Thnx @sfdcfox for the suggestion